# log scale colorbarItem in pyqtgrapth

Tags: pyqt

I am using colorbaritem in pyqtgrapth.

> stops = [0.00005,0.00003,0.0001,0.0003,0.001,0.003,0.01,0.03,0.1,0.3,1],

and I do have my own predefinedd colors which are:

> colors = 255 * np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1], [0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9], [0.83, 0.83, 0.8, 0.9],[0.84, 0.15, 0.74, 0.7], [0.64, 0.07, 0.55, 1], [0.22, 0.36, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0.1, 1],[1, 0, 0, 0.9],[1, 0.96, 0, 1], [1, 0.39, 0, 1],[1, 0, 0, 1]])

I could not find any trick to make my colormapitem to show them in log scale. It gives me a plot like this:
[image]

Anyone knows how should I handle this?
thnx

I tried to make a different class but did not work.

```
stops = np.flipud(np.abs(np.log10(stops)))
self.frog_preview_draw["data"].setImage(np.log10(self.data, where = self.data > 0))
```

Comment: post your code for what you already tried have tried

Comment: my posted is edited with the way I tried. @alexander